# How to get the passed int value in HTML

Tags: java, android, html, regex

I have a String like this:

```
static String name = "what is the language used in android <img height=\""+height+"\" width=\""+width+"\">";
```

I need to get the value of `height` and `width`, which I am passing on the fly.Now i am in a situation where i need to get the values based on individual items.

I have tried regular expression but they are not working.

Comment: You have the height and width to put in the string. Why don't you just use them?

Comment: @nhahtdh yes but i passing the height and widht on the fly and i am in a situation where i nedd to get these values based on individual items

Comment: How do you differentiate between the different items then? Regex will just grab all of them anyway.

Comment: @nhahtdh thats what i am searching for

Comment: You can just store the numbers you have inserted on the fly. I think you should edit your question to add more context to it. Otherwise, it doesn't look like a problem that should be solved with regex.

Comment: Which language are you going to use?

Comment: @nhahtdh no i dont want that as its an expensive approacha also i am not looking to store any where

Comment: @Goofy: I'm not sure how it is less expensive to throw the fish into the sea, then catch them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
int height = 0;
int width = 0;

Pattern h = Pattern.compile("height=\"([0-9]*)\"");
Pattern w = Pattern.compile("width=\"([0-9]*)\"");

Matcher m1 = h.matcher(name);
Matcher m2 = w.matcher(name);

if (m1.find()) {
    height = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(1));
}

if (m2.find()) {
    width = Integer.parseInt(m2.group(1));
}

System.out.println(height);
System.out.println(width);
```

Comment: This won't work. String class `matches` function works differently from other languages.

Comment: @nhahtdh Differently how?

Comment: It will check that the whole string matches the regex. It is like having `^$` put into the regex at the beginning and at the end. You cannot access the captured text also, since this method is meant for validation only.

Comment: It is still useless, since you cannot get the captured text.

Comment: @ATOzTOA it syas invalide character constant for this ' ?

Comment: It is close, but not yet there. I think you should run the code and see for yourself. And you can revert to the original regex you have, since Matcher will work like match function in other languages.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks... it has been ages since I used Java :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple regex:

```
<img\s+height="(\d+)"\s+width="(\d+)"\s*>
```

and yor code:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<img\\s+height=\"(\\d+)\"\\s+width=\"(\\d+)\"\\s*>");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(inputString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
```

explain:

> ***`\d`***
>   Matches any decimal digit.
>
> ***`\s`***
>   Matches any white-space character.
>
> ***`(subexpression)`***
>   Captures the matched subexpression

Comment: With the way it is, you only get the height out of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for getting height:

```
(?<=height=")[^"]*(?=")|(?<=height=')[^']*(?=')
```

Then you can just replace the two instances of `height` with width in that regex to get the width.

This will probably also work and is more succinct:

```
(?<=height=("|')).*?(?=\1)
```

Comment: For the 2nd part, you probably mean `[^']*` rather than `[^"]*`

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes that is what I meant.  Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @JLRishe how to apply to that string? as there is no such method called get

Comment: @Goofy Please search for a tutorial on how to apply a regex in your development platform, with which I am not familiar.  There should be plenty of information available.

Comment: @Goofy: Matcher loop. Check out Pattern and Matcher class for more info. I still think this is a poor idea, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh u mean this matcher.group()?

Comment: @nhahtdh how to get the height using the above regx?

Comment: @JLRishe i am not getting how to use your your solution please tell me